# How to use html2canvas with coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to capture an image in the browser using [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas). Capturing an image of the whole browser works. But I need to specify `x,y` start and end coordinates that I want to capture. [In the docs](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration) I saw that `html2canvas` can accept `x,y` coordinates:

> **x**:    **Default**: Element x-offset   **Description:** Crop canvas x-coordinate
>   **y**:    **Default**: Element y-offset   **Description:** Crop canvas y-coordinate

Passing my `x,y` coordinates to those parameters just captures the whole window.

So instead, I tried capturing the whole window, and then cropping an area from it using [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) *(found at some other stackoverflow post, not sure which)*:

```js
function snapImage(x1,y1,x2,y2, e){
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
        // calc the size -- but no larger than the html2canvas size!
        var width = Math.min(canvas.width,Math.abs(x2-x1));
        var height = Math.min(canvas.height,Math.abs(y2-y1));
        // create a new avatarCanvas with the specified size
        var avatarCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        avatarCanvas.width=width;
        avatarCanvas.height=height;
        avatarCanvas.id = 'avatarCanvas';
        // put avatarCanvas into document body
        document.body.appendChild(avatarCanvas);
        // use the clipping version of drawImage to draw
        // a clipped portion of html2canvas's canvas onto avatarCanvas
        var avatarCtx = avatarCanvas.getContext('2d');
        avatarCtx.drawImage(canvas,x1,y1,width,height,0,0,width,height);
    });
}
```

This draws a shifted image with a wrong offset. For example, given the following website:

[image: demo_website_image]
*image taken from the example at: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/tree/master/examples*

I mark "**pluot?**" area to snap it:

[image: snapping_rectangle_mark]
*see the dotted rectangle*

The dotted rectangle is drawn using js, given the mouse coordinates in 2 events: `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`. Because the rectangle is drawn correctly, I assume my coordinates are correct. But when I pass these coordinates to the function `snapImage()` above, I get the following captured image:

[image: my_captured_image]

Looks like there's an offset. Maybe the start coordinates `drawImage()` operates on differ from my canvas start coordinates?

---

**EDIT:**

**Turns out that my code works when I'm on 100% zoom. It doesn't though when I zoom in / out.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a built-in chrome function [captureVisibleTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab) that captures the image of the active tab. So I ended up using that instead of `html2canvas`. I got help from the [Copyfish Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copyfish-%F0%9F%90%9F-free-ocr-soft/eenjdnjldapjajjofmldgmkjaienebbj?hl=en). Github code here: [Copyfish](https://github.com/A9T9/Copyfish/tree/1cbce8558c63c55cf79223cf741757835510fe78).

Here's my code:

Listener:

```
//listener in background.js which invokes the screen capture
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(function (dataURL) {
    sendResponse({
            dataURL: dataURL,
    });
});
```

Receiver:

```
//receiver in content.js which gets the captured image and crops it accordingly
function(response){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = response.dataURL;
    var dpf = window.innerWidth / img.width;
    var scaleFactor = 1 / dpf,
    sx = Math.min(x1, x2) * scaleFactor,
    sy = Math.min(y1, y2) * scaleFactor,
    width = Math.abs(x2 - x1),
    height = Math.abs(y2 - y1);

    // create a new avatarCanvas with the specified size
    var avatarCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    avatarCanvas.width = width;
    avatarCanvas.height = height;
    avatarCanvas.id = 'avatarCanvas';
    // put avatarCanvas into document body
    document.body.appendChild(avatarCanvas);
    // use the clipping version of drawImage to draw
    var avatarCtx = avatarCanvas.getContext('2d');
    avatarCtx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

`x,y` coordinates are taken by `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` respectively.

This method is zoom- and resolution- proof.

Comment: How did you make this work? How do you call `captureVisibleTab` this method?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is because you get x and y from event with clientX and clientY. Use pageX and pageY instead. Have a look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminotto/x72kuqdz/12/)

```
let startX, startY;

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    console.log("ok");
    startX = Math.floor(event.pageX);
    startY = Math.floor(event.pageY);
});

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    snapImage(Math.min(event.pageX, startX), Math.min(event.pageY, startY), Math.max(event.pageX, startX), Math.max(event.pageY, startY));
});

function snapImage(x1,y1,x2,y2, e){
    console.log(x1, x2, y1, y2);
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
        // calc the size -- but no larger than the html2canvas size!
        var width = Math.min(canvas.width,Math.abs(x2-x1));
        var height = Math.min(canvas.height,Math.abs(y2-y1));
        // create a new avatarCanvas with the specified size
        var avatarCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        avatarCanvas.width=width;
        avatarCanvas.height=height;
        avatarCanvas.id = 'avatarCanvas';
        // put avatarCanvas into document body
        document.body.appendChild(avatarCanvas);
        // use the clipping version of drawImage to draw
        // a clipped portion of html2canvas's canvas onto avatarCanvas
        var avatarCtx = avatarCanvas.getContext('2d');
        avatarCtx.drawImage(canvas,x1,y1,width,height,0,0,width,height);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have 2 monitors of different sizes in extended mode, and your code works only on the smaller monitor. When I move the browser window to the bigger screen, I get a similar problem like the one I had

Comment: Also on zooming in and out your solution doesn't quite work... Actually I just figured out that without zoom even my solution works...